# Function not executing in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, mist, tokens

I copied a smart contract and deployed it from my account on Mist on Rinkeby Network.

All functions are working as expected except one. I will post the code here :

```
event PerformingDrop(uint count);
function drop(address[] addresses, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
  uint256 amt = amount * 10**8;
  require(amt > 0);
  require(amt <= SUPPLY_CAP);
  PerformingDrop(addresses.length);

  // Maximum drop is 1000 addresses
  assert(addresses.length <= 1000);
  assert(balances[owner] >= amt * addresses.length);
  for (uint i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    address recipient = addresses[i];
    if(recipient != NULL_ADDRESS) {
      balances[owner] -= amt;
      balances[recipient] += amt;
      Transfer(owner, recipient, amt);
     }
   }
 }
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of error]

I am executing this contract from my main account which has 2.97 ether available.

- No of Tokens: 10000000.00000000
- Decimals : 8

I am passing array of addresses as 1st param e.g [‘Address1’, ‘ Address2’] and number of tokens to drop.

Whenever I perform a drop of 10000000 drop works fine but if I increase even 1 more digit let say 100000000 then the error shown in image occurs.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is this line in the contract,

```
  uint256 amt = amount * 10**8;
```

This means that your input number of tokens is being multiplied up to account for the 8 decimal places.

Therefore, your input needs to be in terms of *whole* tokens. If you have 10000000.00000000 tokens in your account, then your maximum input can be 10000000, divided by the number of addresses.  (Incidentally, since you can't input fractions, this means that the 8 decimal places are totally pointless...)

Comment: Yeah i also believe thats an issue. Let me test and get back to you.

Comment: After i removed "* 10**8" from that statement i didn't get that error and transaction runs successfully but tokens dropped are not showing up in the receivers account.

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting removing that line, just being aware of it so that your input amount, transaction amount and `decimals` parameter are all consistent. If you do remove it, then you can set `decimals` to zero and everything will be much clearer (you'll always be dealing in whole tokens throughout, so no confusion).

Comment: what are the drawbacks of not having decimals?

Comment: None at all, in my view: they seem to be an endless source of confusion. In ERC20, the `decimals` parameter is just for the UI - it has no internal meaning in the contract. Some UIs handle it and some don't, just adding to the confusion. Better off without, I say.  But decimals might make sense in some use cases, so the facility is there if you want it.

Comment: Hi @pankaj - Did this answer your question? If so it would be good to mark it as answered for the benefit of others.